# PHP function use variable from another function

Tags: php

I was wondering if there's a way to use a `$result` variable declared in another function.

```
function test1($day){ 

     $_SESSION['result'] = array_reduce($day, function($cur, $x)
 { 
return $cur + $x[2];
 }, 0);
}
```

and I need that `$result` variable in another function :

```
function test2($general){

    $general = explode("\n", $general) ; 
    foreach ($general as $key => $value)
    $general[$key] = explode(" ", $value) ; 

    $general[2][1]=$_SESSION['result'];
 }
```

But it doesn't display the value until I refresh. Is there a better way to have tha var get recognized in the second function?

Thanks

Comment: One question: why do that? (hint: why don't just pass desired value?)

Comment: can't you use global variable? like: `global $result;`

Comment: Since the variable is `$_SESSION` and that's a super global, this should work as is.

Comment: @RezaMamun Please NEVER use a global. There is no reason to do so in any imaginable scenario. It will only create loads of trouble for you!

Comment: how are these two functions related? If one is called before the other, why are they even separate functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function test1(){
    $name = "ABC";
    return $name;
}

$result = test1();

function test2($result){
    $string = "My name is $result";
    echo $string;
}

test2($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the result like you would normally do:

```
function one(){
    return "some result";
}

function two($input){
    return "something else and ".$input;
}

$value = one();
$anothervalue = two($value);
echo $anothervalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Read about variable scope 
[Scope in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)